# Identify this movie about Law Enforcement/ drug cartels

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw a few scenes of a movie that seemed interesting. I'd like to find it, but I can't remember much...

The production quality made it seem like a recent movie (< 5 yrs)
Set in USA, Southwest border (Texas? New Mexico?)

The scenes I saw:

- bank robbery (stealing from cartel)
- the protagonist escapes his captors (maybe police? military) running in some deserty canyon landscape. They shoot at him. I don't know all the context.
- the protagonist later is in a building at night and meets with a dirty cop or something. People outside (maybe another protagonist? antagonist?) start sniping people in the building. I think the people in the building figure out they were set up. I distinctly remember one character aiming through a scope at the other while they are talking.
- I vaguely recall the people talking back and forth to each other in the building while looking around for each other (guns drawn?)
- later,  I think the dirty cop gets confronted at his home or office and I think killed with a desert eagle... maybe?
- I think the two main characters have to team up to bring the people responsible to justice?

General topic: Cartels? bribes? dirty cops? betrayal? set up?

Sorry, I only saw brief scenes on a restaurant TV and I can't remember the actors. It has been a while.

Comment: We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions  or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: [**Identify-This-X Questions**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Sudip is dead on, that was The Negotiator.

Comment: This is one of the best structured ID questions I have come across here +1 for that!

Comment: @SudipBiswas  Where did your answer go !?!?!?!! That was a nice reply and I was stunned that it contracted a negative vote (which I promptly erased by upvoting) and now.... it's all gone, including the trailer clip you embedded.

Comment: @UncertainWhatNameToPickHere Sorry I deleted it. :) Thanks for the vote though! Once the OP confirmed that, that wasn't the movie he was looking for. Had it be a plot-explanation or analysis question I would'av left it there, but being an ID question, I felt it was wastage of space.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it by any chance 2 Guns? (2013)

Youtube link:

Imdb link: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1272878/

There is a bank robbery in this movie, it occurs in Mexico and the two main charcaters vow to take down the cartel and some such...

Comment: Thank you! I looked up the scenes. It was the navy guys that betray Mark Wahlberg in the desert somewhere that I remembered!